# My toolbar buttons are disappearing after two entries

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs, toolbar, tabbedpage

I have successfully created my app and am finally ready to start testing before continuing with designs, however, while testing I find that after using my toolbar buttons twice it just disappears for no reason.
Here is the Xaml code for the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ODDJOBS.Views"
             x:Class="ODDJOBS.Views.TabbedAppPage">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="ODDJOBS" Priority="1"></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="+" Priority="2" Command="{Binding NavigateToAddPageCommand}">
        </ToolbarItem>
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
  <pages:NextPage Title="Jobs"/>
  <pages:ServiceView Title="Services"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Comparing the images, looks like toolbar scrolled off the top of the page. Add to question the c# for method called by `NavigateToAddPageCommand`. ALSO, why is the XAML listed TWICE?

Comment: AND, how do you navigate to that page? `MainPage = new TabbedAppPage();`, or something different?

Comment: That was a mistake when i was copying the code it's only on there once (fixed now)

Comment: I use a navigation dispatcher

Comment: Why did you delete the images? They show what was happening. As it stands now, the question lacks enough information for anyone to help. Anyway, toolbar scrolling off top of page should only happen if the page is wrapped inside something else, such as an AppShell. In App.xaml.cs, show the line you have for `MainPage = ???;`